# Ubuntu 16.04 Nvidia Geforce 940MX wakeup problem black screen

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

Seen a couple of similar questions out there, but no answer helped me fixed it

Asus UX410U
Core i7 7th Gen
Nvidia Geforce 940MX
Ubuntu 16.04
installed : sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
Tried proprietary drivers version 384.98 and 387.12

Wakeup from suspend used to not work with default proprietary drivers
Then a month ago or so, it was working, after I added the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
Then something like 2 weeks ago, it stopped working (I'm doing update/upgrade every week or so)
When waking up from suspend, the screen stays black, and fan are at maximum speed

I accessed the laptop using another PC and ssh, to check on dmesg.txt, and got :

```
[ 3583.698536] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 3583.708045] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[ 3584.323202] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 3584.324931] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
[ 3584.325746] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[ 3584.325784] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 3584.435877] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 3584.435997] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[ 3584.436266] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 3584.437583] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 3584.440770] ACPI : EC: event blocked
[ 3584.723278] PM: suspend of devices complete after 288.871 msecs
[ 3584.745836] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 22.550 msecs
[ 3584.747247] ACPI : EC: interrupt blocked
[ 3584.749776] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 3584.793841] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 47.999 msecs
[ 3584.794882] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 3584.798931] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[ 3584.798932] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 3584.799006] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 3584.799778] Broke affinity for irq 125
[ 3584.800872] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 3584.815388] Broke affinity for irq 122
[ 3584.815396] Broke affinity for irq 123
[ 3584.815403] Broke affinity for irq 124
[ 3584.815411] Broke affinity for irq 125
[ 3584.815419] Broke affinity for irq 128
[ 3584.815427] Broke affinity for irq 129
[ 3584.817780] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 3584.850886] Broke affinity for irq 1
[ 3584.850894] Broke affinity for irq 8
[ 3584.850898] Broke affinity for irq 9
[ 3584.850906] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 3584.850913] Broke affinity for irq 17
[ 3584.850923] Broke affinity for irq 109
[ 3584.850931] Broke affinity for irq 122
[ 3584.850935] Broke affinity for irq 123
[ 3584.850939] Broke affinity for irq 124
[ 3584.850943] Broke affinity for irq 125
[ 3584.850948] Broke affinity for irq 126
[ 3584.850954] Broke affinity for irq 128
[ 3584.850958] Broke affinity for irq 129
[ 3584.852032] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 3584.873651] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 3584.873758] ACPI : EC: EC started
[ 3584.873759] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 3584.874512] Suspended for 4.914 seconds
[ 3584.875728] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 3584.886000] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 3584.886000] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 3584.886549]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 3584.886664] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x38
[ 3584.887625] microcode: updated to revision 0x62, date = 2017-04-27
[ 3584.887693] CPU1 is up
[ 3584.898105] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[ 3584.899262]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 3584.899438] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x62
[ 3584.899593] CPU2 is up
[ 3584.914187] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[ 3584.915260]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 3584.915633] CPU3 is up
[ 3584.923752] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 3584.935853] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[ 3584.935972] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[ 3584.936091] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[ 3584.936209] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[ 3584.936326] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[ 3584.936443] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[ 3584.936560] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[ 3584.936676] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[ 3584.936793] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[ 3584.936910] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937027] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937144] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937261] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937378] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937500] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937617] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937735] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937870] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[ 3584.937990] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
[ 3584.938324] ACPI : EC: interrupt unblocked
[ 3584.980120] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 3584.980395] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 42.275 msecs
[ 3584.994246] PM: early resume of devices complete after 13.810 msecs
[ 3584.994458] ACPI : EC: event unblocked
[ 3584.994593] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 3584.994595] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 3584.994610] ACPI : button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
[ 3584.995178] rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 3584.997960] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 3584.997971] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[ 3585.043147] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[ 3585.314045] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3585.323368] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 3585.341937] usb 1-8: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 3585.602119] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3585.788000] PM: resume of devices complete after 793.750 msecs
[ 3585.788315] usb 1-8:1.0: rebind failed: -517
[ 3585.788320] usb 1-8:1.1: rebind failed: -517
[ 3585.788916] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 3585.788918] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 3585.804930] thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-5)
[ 3585.828561] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 3585.835610] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 3585.835611] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 3585.835611] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 3585.835612] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 3585.835612] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 3585.835613] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 3585.835615] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 3587.061841] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3587.065193] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 3587.098059] [drm] RC6 on
[ 3587.109203] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 3587.111819] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3587.112876] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3587.243123] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3587.243347] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 3587.243475] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3587.243562] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1387949 usecs
[ 3587.243573] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 3587.254528] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10707 usecs
[ 3587.254576] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 3587.258565] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 3587.322491] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 3587.374068] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 3592.345855] wlp2s0: authenticate with a0:8e:78:03:3b:5f
[ 3592.353904] wlp2s0: send auth to a0:8e:78:03:3b:5f (try 1/3)
[ 3592.369878] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 3592.373796] wlp2s0: associate with a0:8e:78:03:3b:5f (try 1/3)
[ 3592.378865] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from a0:8e:78:03:3b:5f (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3592.381249] wlp2s0: associated
[ 3592.381325] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 3592.397838] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by a0:8e:78:03:3b:5f
```

Then from ssh I tried restarting the lightdm service, but it didn't help to get back to GUI. I could see some prints on the screen, lines like terminal, but the system was still unresponsive from local keyboard (only ssh worked)

Trying to restart lightdm services added the following line on dmesg

```
[ 3888.802812] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.067871] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.068009] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.068095] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.068195] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.068296] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.068425] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.068486] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.072812] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.140526] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3889.142392] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1113)
[ 3889.142513] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[ 3892.769231] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.769339] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.769415] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.769488] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.769558] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.769669] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.769741] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.773834] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.840339] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3892.842131] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1113)
[ 3892.842169] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[ 3893.883374] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.883436] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.883474] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.883508] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.883542] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.883595] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.883629] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.887110] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.961197] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3893.963068] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1113)
[ 3893.963113] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[ 3894.865583] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.865624] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.865646] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.865666] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.865685] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.865715] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.865735] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.867873] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.931121] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3894.932975] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1113)
[ 3894.933019] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[ 3895.832079] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.832118] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.832139] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.832159] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.832178] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.832209] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.832229] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.834274] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.895720] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)
[ 3895.897523] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1113)
[ 3895.897561] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
```

There's clearly a problem with the nvidia driver, as suspend/resume works fine with open source driver
I hope those details help identifying the problem
Please do ask for more details if needed

Comment: I highly doubt this is the issue, but have you tried disabling secure boot?

Comment: @AndroidDev Tried that before, didn't help. Just tried it again.... and it didn't help. If you doubt that is the issue, can you elaborate ?